# React-Native button press after textInput in Keyboard aware scroll view

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem where I have a **TextInput** and a **button** inside a `KeyboardAwareScrollView`. I want the user to input some text and then press the **button** made with **TouchableOpacity**. This sends the text forward that the user just inputted.

Problem is that after inputting text, one first try **TextInput** merely loses focus. Only on the next press attempt is the **butto**n actually pressed. How can I have the button react on the first press?

I am using this package https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

My code is as follows:

```
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        <TextInput
          style={{ width: 100, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity 
          style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', width: 50, height: 50 }}
        />
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please use **keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'** on ScrollView. Below is how to do it.

```
<ScrollView
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always' >
</ScrollView>
```

It's happening because `ScrollView` has property to dismiss the keyboard first and then it will allow actions to its child views. Now we are changing that behavior with above property.

Comment: Why does this change whether I can press things outside of the Scrollview though?

Comment: If the scrollview or scrollview children components on top, it will try to dismiss the keyboard first.

Comment: Please do let me know, in case if my answer is different from what you asked

Comment: Hey, you answered what I asked about :) Cheers